# R: Creating a factor from two different numerical vectors' values

Tags: r

as a newbie in R, I got stuck to this issue of data manipulation:
I need to create a factor with 4 levels from to two numerical vectors (enable, restrict). The latter are factor scores.

The 4 levels should be:

- level 1 = data$enable > median(data$enable) & data$restrict > median(data$restrict)
- level 2 =  data$enable < median (data$enable) & data$restrict > median (data$restrict)

and the following two more combinations. I want to label the levels as well.
I am not sure how to nest it in the factor() function.

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: could you share an example of your data to work with

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: everything that's described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could use `ifelse`

Comment: Data are confidential, I can share a data frame with the two variables that needs recoding into to a factor. Would that work?

Comment: Try `with(data, ifelse(enable > median(enable)  & restrict  > median(restrict),
           1, ifelse(enable < median(enable) & restrict > median(restrict),
           2, ifelse(enable > median(enable) & restrict < median(restrict),
           3, 4))))` and then wrap it with `factor` if necessary.

Comment: I have got this error Error in ifelse((enabling < median(enabling) & restrictive < median(restrictive,  : 
  argument "yes" is missing, with no default

Comment: Using
style <- factor(with(data, ifelse(enabling > median(enabling) & restrictive > median(restrictive), 1, 
                  ifelse(enabling < median(enabling) & restrictive > median(restrictive), 2, 
                  ifelse(enabling > median(enabling) & restrictive < median(restrictive), 3, 
                  ifelse((enabling < median(enabling) & restrictive < median(restrictive, 4)))))

Comment: You haven't given any example.  Based on the example I provided below, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using nested `ifelse`

```
with(data, 
   ifelse(enable > median(enable)  & restrict  > median(restrict),1, 
   ifelse(enable < median(enable) & restrict > median(restrict), 2, 
   ifelse(enable > median(enable) & restrict < median(restrict), 3,
      4))))
#[1] 2 4 1 2 3 1 4 3 1 4
```

---

Or another option would be to get the `colMedians` (from `library(matrixStats)`) of the dataset, check whether the data is greater than the column medians, add 1 to the logical index to convert it to a 1/2 values, `paste` the columns together, convert to `factor` and then if needed can be coerced to `numeric`.

```
library(matrixStats)
factor(do.call(paste0,  as.data.frame((data >
      colMedians(as.matrix(data))[col(data)])+1L)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(enable = sample(20, 10, replace=TRUE),
           restrict = sample(20, 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: The first option worked well. I have just wrapped as a new factor. Many thanks!